# iOS: Refactor Large XIB into a few smaller XIB files for speed

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, xib, nib

When watching some of the `WWDC2011 videos` it was mentioned that large `nib files` can make your app take some time to load.  This isn't necessarily the case with my app, but I feel like my `nib` is fairly large.  The suggestion on the video was to make that large `nib` into a few smaller ones for quick load time.

Maybe I am missing something, but how would I split up a large `nib` into smaller ones?  My `UIViewController` will only load one `nib` when it inits.  Is there another way to do it will multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted you can init a `UIViewController` with a specified nib to load its `view` property and that's only a single file. However you need not pack all of your `view` property's subviews into the same nib file. If you have some subviews which are only visible some of the time consider splitting them out into their own nib files and loading them on demand using `UINib`. If you have a set of `UITableViewCell` subclasses or tiles for a `UIScrollView`'s content you probably want to be able to load only the view instances you actually need and not a massive nib containing extraneous views (e.g. loading all of your table cells when you only use one of them).

Comment: Ok, using UINib sounds like a good idea.  So if I have a UIView in another nib file, I can just call [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil]; and it will return my UIView object?

Comment: No. `+nibWithNibName:bundle:` will return a UINib object. You can then call `-instantiateWithOwner:options:` on that UINib instance which returns an array of all top level objects found in the nib and connects any bindings with the "owner" you provide. You can obtain the objects from your nib from that array if need be but I prefer to pass an owner which will have some property bound to the object loaded from the nib. (http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)